# jQuery working for client, Not in Dev Tools

Tags: jquery, console

Strange enough I see jQuery loaded in the header of this site, the frame work uses jquery consistently, but try testing jquery in the console.   You will be told that 'undefined' is not a function.

Any ideas?  Haven't been able to straighten it out.  And i really do not want to write strict js.  Not fun.  I even switch up jquery to cdn to see if we had a corrupted file.  Not the case.

Site:
http://goinfinity.net/

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 1):

Only the `$` object is undefined. If you check for `jQuery` itself you will see that it is there (and `$` is just a short hand alias for `jQuery`). There can be two reasons for this:

1. [jQuery.noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) - Which runs jQuery in noConflict mode restoring `$` to its original value (which was `undefined` in this case)
2. [require-jquery](https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery) using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and only exposes $ locally

Comment: awesome, i figured there was some kind of jquery strict setting in this theme.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work, use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the amount of scripts looks to be huge, `$` is probably mapped to `jQuery` for noConflict.

Looks like `jQuery` in the console does return the library.